# RPi 3B+ won't discover PC on bluetooth

Tags: bluetooth, bluez

I am trying to connect my Windows 10 PC and RPi via Bluetooth, but my RPi doesn't show my PC as an available device. My PC also does not show my RPi as available.

It is weird because my phone can connect to both the RPi and PC. Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: can your pi connect **to** your phone? can your pc connect **to** your phone? or do you initiate the connection in both cases with your phone? Some device initiates the connection, and some device accepts the connection ... if you are trying to connect two devices that only accept connections but don't initiate them, then they won't connect - I'm not conversant with the many ways bluetooth devices operate, but this part at least seems obvious

Comment: I can connect my pi and phone both ways, and pc and phone both ways. But on the pi my pc doesn't even show up and on my PC the pi doesn't show up

Comment: connect "both ways" ... what does that mean? how do you connect to your phone from your pi? bit of detail in the question of what you CAN do, and HOW you do it

Comment: Both devices show the other in their list of available devices and I can select it to connect